# Advanced custom fields not showing with ACF pro

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to make a couple of advanced fields to show in my live site (running ACF pro) from my local (free ACF) using the following syntax:

```
<h1><?php the_field('homepage_header'); ?></h1>
```

However the **h1** tag shows as empty. Is there a  way to display the fields in ACF pro version 5.3.1 that is different from the free version (Version 4.4.4)?

Comment: Where are you setting the homepage_header value? On an options page? From what I can see theres nothing that should be affecting your simple code above (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/upgrading-v4-v5/).

Comment: Hi there seemed to be an issue with the different versions of the ACF being installed silmultaneously. I have disabled Advanced Custom Fields free version and it seemed to have fixed the issue.